# Erro de exceção ao executar meu código no Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Está aparecendo o seguinte erro quando escolho as três primeiras opções que criei no meu código:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException:
> Conversion = '2'  at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)    at
> java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)     at
> java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)    at
> java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)    at
> java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)    at
> ContaCorrente.main(ContaCorrente.java:37)

Meu código em Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContaCorrente {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        float saldoTotal = 1000;
        int statusAtual;
        int opcaoEscolha;
        
        Scanner input;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        do {
            System.out.print("Olá! O que você deseja fazer? "
                    + "\n 1 - Realizar o saque "
                    + "\n 2 - Realizar depósito "
                    + "\n 3 - Consultar o saldo "
                    + "\n 4 - Verificar o status da conta"
                    + "\n 5 - Sair \n");
            opcaoEscolha = input.nextInt();
            switch(opcaoEscolha){
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Quantos R$ você deseja sacar? \n");
                float valorSacado = input.nextFloat();
                if(valorSacado > saldoTotal)
                    System.out.print("Saldo insuficiente! \n");
                else {
                    saldoTotal = (valorSacado - saldoTotal); 
                    System.out.printf("O valor retirado foi de R$ %2.f ", valorSacado + "\n");
                    System.out.printf("O valor atual é de R$ %2.f", saldoTotal + "\n");
                }
            case 2:
                System.out.print("Quantos R$ você deseja depositar em sua conta? \n");
                float valorDeposito = input.nextFloat();
                saldoTotal = (valorDeposito + saldoTotal);
                System.out.printf("O seu saldo atual é de R$ %2.f", saldoTotal + "\n");
            case 3:
                System.out.printf("Seu saldo atual é de R$ %2.f", saldoTotal + "\n");
            case 4:
                if(saldoTotal > 1000)
                    System.out.print("A sua conta tem o status de 'Especial', parabéns! \n");
                else {
                    System.out.print("Sua conta possui o status 'normal'. \n");
                }
            case 5:
                System.out.print("Até mais!");
            }
        } while(opcaoEscolha != 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Notei que você não usa `break` ao final de cada `case`. Deveria usar, caso contrário a execução continua de um case para outro e acho que não é isso que você quer.

Comment: Coloquei eles, mas continuaram dando o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está usando `printf()` errado.

Troque:

```
System.out.printf("Seu saldo atual é de R$ %2.f", saldoTotal + "\n");
```

por:

```
System.out.printf("Seu saldo atual é de R$ %2.f\n", saldoTotal);
```

Comment: Valeu! Porém ainda estou com o problema :/

Comment: Acho que o erro é usar `%2.f` em vez de `%.2f`, não tenho certeza. Em todo caso o erro está na forma como o `printf()` está sendo feito, estude como usá-lo corretamente, por exemplo na documentação do método.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, estava errando na sintaxe do %.2f e %d. Muito obrigado!!!